# Scripting or adding hotkeys to virtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running virtualBox on linux to run an old game i own (UFO). It it really does not like modern computers. i have to have a really slow CPU for it to be playable.

I found the sweet spot to be 8% of the CPU. But at some other times, like when i boot up or shutdown the machine, or when I'm just navigating trhu the game menus I'd like CPU to much faster.

What i do now is keep entering the settings, going to system, clicking the CPU tab, and sliding the cpu execution cap back and forth. It is a minimum of one two hand key presses (right crlt+s), and 5 clicks, all in opposing corners of the screen. So it is a pain to do that repeatedly.

Is there any way to came up with a "turbo" hotkey solution? either by adding a hotkey to change the execution cap setting directly of by assigning it on my window manager to trigger a script that does that?

I couldn't find any documented API to change runtime settings on a vbox and neither hotkeys settigns withing the client.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When VM is off:
`vboxmanage modifyvm discus --cpuexecutioncap 99`

When VM is on:
`vboxmanage controlvm discus cpuexecutioncap 8`